# What's the difference between HashMap and MutableMap in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Lots of documents have indicated the difference between Map and MutableMap in Kotlin, however, I can't seem to find the difference between HashMap and MutableMap. Can they be used interchangeably? Are there any differences in the implementation level of this 2 data structure? Can someone please elaborate.

And as people have pointed out that MutableMap is an interface. Then when I use a map, what's the difference between using mutableMapOf and hashMapOf?

Thanks.

Comment: [`MutableMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/index.html) is an interface. [`HashMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/index.html) implements it. I'd recommend checking the docs.

Comment: A mutable map is a map that is mutable. It's an interface. And it has plenty of implementstions (HashMap, TreeMap, ConcurrentHashMap, etc.). A HashMap is a specific implementation of a (Mutable)Map. The api doc is your friend. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/index.html, https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/index.html

Comment: `mutableMapOf` returns _some_ implementation, which might be, but is not necessarily, a `HashMap`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks a lot. I think your answer tells what I was looking for.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`HashMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/index.html) is an implementation of the interface [`MutableMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/index.html). From the former link:

> Hash table based implementation of the `MutableMap` interface.

There can be other implementations, like [`LinkedHashMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-linked-hash-map/index.html). You can read the documentation at these links to discover which behaviors are common to all `MutableMap` implementations, and which are specific to `HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Note that `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` are platform dependent (or could be), whereas using the more generic functions such as `mutableMapOf(...)` will create an instance of whatever is considered the default implementation for that platform.

Comment: Ah, so it's intended for non-Java build targets